# WLAN card as LAN interface?

Tags: wifi, local-area-network, pfsense

I have a system with 2 network adapters: a wifi card (atheros) and an ethernet card. 
Both network adapters are recognized by pfsense 2.1 without problems, but I don't know how to configure it:

I want to use the wifi card as LAN interface, the ethernet card as WAN (DSL modem will be connected to it). During the first boot of pfsense I can assign the wifi card as LAN interface, but of course I can't access the pfsense system, as the WLAN itself is not yet configured.

So, what's the way to go here?

Comment: Configure it from the other interface?

Comment: By default there's no access to the web interface from the WAN interface, so that's not an option. Or is there some way to enable access to the web interface from WAN using the console menu?

Comment: It's only a WAN interface because you set it up as one. So don't do that until after you've gotten the wireless working.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I don't understand how to do that. If I assign the ethernet card as LAN then yes, I can access the web interface. But then I can't add the wifi card as LAN interface, as the LAN interface already exists?

Comment: I could probably use the script easyrule to allow access to the web interface from WAN: https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/I_locked_myself_out_of_the_WebGUI,_help!#Add_firewall_rule_at_the_command_line_with_easyrule

Answer (score 1):

pfsense admin gui listens on all interfaces, but its being blocked on wan by default.... just add a rule to the WAN interface allowing 80 and/or 443

you dont need easyrule via cli, just navigate over to the firewall tab, and do this:

http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=37376.0

Comment: well, as long as I have the WLAN card as LAN but no WLAN configured, I have to use the CLI, because I can't access the webinterface.